# Headphones picking up output sound

Tags: windows-10, headphones

I'm having trouble with my headphones picking up output sound. I'm using an analog headphones with the green and pink 3.5mm jack I also have a speaker plugged in.

First of all Stereo Mix is already disabled, second the "Listen to this device." on my microphone's settings is unchecked, third playback on realtek HD Audio Manager is muted.

I don't know what to do anymore, my speaker is turned off when I am using my headphones so the echo and music isn't coming from my speaker. If I try to record on audacity even though my mic is turned off the music I'm playing will be recorded. I tried removing my speaker but it doesn't work. I tried removing the green jack, well it works if my mic is turned off but as soon as I turn on my mic it starts to record both my voice and the music. I tried removing the pink jack and the echo is still there. I also tried using a different headphones but it didn't fix it. the only way I fixed the problem is removing the headphone completely which is completely useless since I need it.

I don't know when this started. I just took notice of this since me and my girlfriend started to voice chat over steam and she can hear her own voice which I thought was a problem on her side but when I tried to record something on audacity it was clearly on my end. I also tried disabling NVIDIA HD Audio on Device Manager but still no luck.

Here are some pictures that may help you guys see if I did something wrong.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSZp8.jpg